# Is it possible to sell stolen items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently discovered the average shopkeeper is unwilling to buy stolen goods (how they know they are stolen, I do not know).

Is there anyway for me to sell stolen items, without making use of the console?

Comment: And another hello to our friends at law enforcement stumbling across this site via web keyword searches...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're going to need access to a Fence if you want to sell your [bucket-gotten gains](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rt5aUdijAN8). The Thieves guild provides access to them (after completing the 2nd quest).

You might also be interested in the 'Fence' perk in the Speech tree.

> You can sell stolen goods to any merchant you have invested in.

Comment: Hmmm, bucket-gotten gains, the best kind.

Comment: can you sell stolen goods at the kajiit caravane that goes around?

Comment: @Sam you'll be able to get access to fences in Khajiit caravans (separate from a caravan's main merchant) through Thieves Guild quests.

Answer (score 16):

The standard route is through Guild fences or by achieving a high-level speech perk that allows you to do so.  I'm not a big fan of the speech perks, though - by the time you get to the high-level benefits, you don't really need them anymore - and Guild fences are few and far between even after going through the Guild quest line.

An alternative, for the skilled pickpocket, is to reverse-pickpocket your stolen items onto bandits or other enemies.  Then kill them.  Then take your legitimately-earned loot, without 'stolen' tags, from the corpse.

Comment: Ingenious!54321

Comment: This has been patched and no longer works

Answer (score 4):

The thieves guild is in Riften. After a couple initiation quests you will be allowed to sell all stolen goods to Tonilia.

Answer (score 2):

I read if you drop an item in front of a friendly hero they will pick it up and give it to you. This removes the stolen 'tag' on the item.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you read this?