# My follower attacks me when I pick up stolen items in my house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I built my Lakeview manor house and I decided to try and pimp it out and make it look cool. Try being the key word. Most of my items are stolen, just because I steal a lot, and for some stupid reason, getting my follower to empty chests and carry a crap load of items for me seems to make them all of a sudden stolen.

Anyways, when place a stolen weapon, lets say, in a display case and then decide I want to move it or use it, my follower (Ogol) give me a bounty and turns on me. He gives me the option to pay or else.  If I dont pay he leave my service and attacks me and that also turns my housecarl after me as well.

I know this stupid place has so many damn bugs it isn't funny but I'm not sure if this has anything at all to do with the house or not.  Is there anyway to prevent this? Anything I can do at all? I just built my second house at another location because the glitches and bug really scare me. My items have been getting moved around and even vanished after leaving and coming back. The only good thing about the bugs are, for whatever reason one of my mannequins keeps spawning a $5000 piece of ebony mail and a ebony shield every time I leave the area, so its making me a lot of money. But I'd really love to use my house and not worry.

So does anyone have any suggestions or does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: The Hearthfire DLC is the buggiest I have ever come across. From duping gear to ragdoll dragons humping the ground. (I called mine Toad.)

Comment: the items moving and vanishing is a different bug.  If you place the item after moving again it should stay in place next time the area loads, but everytime you place an object in skyrim and you zone out it'll fall onto the ground (sometimes clipping through the ground and go missing) when you zone back.

Answer (score 8):

The follower's action is not a bug.  Some followers are morally conscious and will report any crime you commit while others may not care as much.

You can look up whether or not a follower cares about crime in [this UESP page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers).

The other thing you can do is to '[launder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37085/is-it-possible-to-remove-stolen-status-from-stolen-items)'  your items to remove their 'stolen' status.

Comment: And how does someone launder items?

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. Technically you are "re-stealing" the item. It doesn't matter what the item's location is, if it's marked as stolen and you pick it up, you just stole something.

Some followers are morally good and will attack you if you steal anything.

Comment: well the thing is, he doesnt do this to me when i steal stuff from anywhere else. I can steal all day long from store and what not and my follower has never done anything.  i only get a bounty when i pick up a stolen item in my house and the bounty i get goes away as soon as i pay my follower the gold he demands lol

Comment: Your follower demands the payment? Is your follower from a mod or something? Only guards demand payment as far as I know.

Comment: Yes its really wierd! the bounty comes from my follower Ogol. Hes an orc that comes from that little orc settlement. Im 99% sure he isnt from any DLC.  Its so wierd, as soon as i pick up my items he runs over to me and give me the option to pay or not and if I dont pay him the money he attacks me. When i do pay him the money, he says something along the lines of.... "this money will go good towards helping the clan"  something like that.   I have no idea what to do or why its happening. It only happens when i steal from my house, he lets me steal anywhere else I want, I do it all the time

Answer (score -2):

turning yourself in is the only way to make it stop

Comment: What does this add that isn't covered by existing answers? These duplicated answers are subject to deletion here. We, are, not, a, forum.