# How can I remove the stolen tag from items without using pickpocketing, killing people, or using fences?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a ton of stolen jewelry, and no way to sell it. What should I do?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to sell stolen items?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35036/is-it-possible-to-sell-stolen-items?rq=1=)

Comment: Edited the question a bit

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the [Khajit hidden chests](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Khajiit_Caravans#Trivia), they can be used to remove the stolen tag for free with no requirements other than having the stolen item and money to pay for it.

1. Find the chest and make sure that the khajit merchant is nearby.
2. Insert the stolen item(s) into the chest.
3. The merchant will now have the item in stock. Buy it.
4. Loot the chest to get your gold back.

Comment: Shame this pretty much is an exploit. A lot of people, including me, don't like using those.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an exploit just because you don't like to use it. It's part of the game, and it fits in with the skyrim lore for khajit merchants. Also, I think it makes sense to some degree as a way of laundering goods, from a logical standpoint.

Comment: May be worth pointing out that on PCs, the unofficial patch fixes this, i.e. the chests are no longer accessible (without using the console).